# SQL Select latest row by date

Tags: sql, select, group-by, max, getlatest

I have a large amount of data that updates every 10 minutes or so.

There are 128 unique ID's that need to be returned but with only there latest values

**CURRENT CODE**

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
id, 
MAX(extractdate) AS [extractdate],
total,
used,
free

FROM
maintable
INNER JOIN datatable ON maintable.unkey = datatable.dataunkey

GROUP BY id, total, used, free

ORDER BY id
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
id      extractdate                 total   used    free
1       2014-08-28 00:20:00.000     50      20      30
1       2014-08-28 00:30:00.000     50      30      20
1       2014-08-28 00:40:00.000     50      10      40
2       2014-08-28 00:20:00.000     50      20      30
2       2014-08-28 00:30:00.000     50      30      20
2       2014-08-28 00:40:00.000     50      25      25
etc etc

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

id      extractdate                 total   used    free
1       2014-08-28 00:40:00.000     50      10      40
2       2014-08-28 00:40:00.000     50      25      25
etc etc
```

Comment: what dbms is this for (it really does matter), and: you never need `DISTINCT` if you are already doing `GROUP BY`

Comment: SSMS - I removed it and still the same

Comment: "I removed it and still the same" yes, exactly. I was pointing out that you do not need distinct if using group by because it is redundant (not as the solution to Question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT 
a.id,
a.extractdate,
a.total,
a.used,
a.free
FROM(
SELECT  
id, 
MAX(extractdate) AS [extractdate],
total,
used,
free,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by id ORDER BY MAX(extractdate) desc) AS rnk
FROM maintable
INNER JOIN datatable ON maintable.unkey = datatable.dataunkey
GROUP BY id, total, used, free )a
WHERE a.rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work, i've just tested it on the similar fall, only without join:

```
SELECT id, extractdate,total,used,free
FROM maintable m INNER JOIN datatable ON m.unkey = datatable.dataunkey
where extractdate = (select max(extractdate) from manitable m1 where m1.id = m.id) 
ORDER BY id
```

Comment: nearly there

    The multi-part identifier "maintable.unkey" could not be bound.