# Select latest Rows by date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a large of transctions daily on my table.
I wanted to only get the **last** transaction happened on that day.

I'm tying to copy [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25547436/sql-select-latest-row-by-date) but I can't implement it on my own

here is my script

```
  SELECT
product_id
,product_name
,stock_on_hand
,stock_in
,stock_out
,date_track
FROM stocks_history
WHERE
product_id = 30
AND
date_track between '9/1/16' and '9/9/16'
```

and this is my result as of the moment

[image]

this is my desired output

[image]

how could I get only the last transaction happened on that day using datetime only?

Comment: Is there a column with the time or a complete timestamp?

Comment: How do you know what the last transaction is?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no last row unless a column specifies the ordering.

Comment: @redneb I'm just using date here.

Comment: If you're just using date, then either of those rows can be last. There's no distinction between them.

Comment: @GordonLinoff in the table above the last row for each date is my last transaction.

Comment: @rainalasa How do you know? There is no guarantee that the order at which rows are returned by a `SELECT` is the same as the order they were inserted. The only reliable way to know the order is if you also record the time in the table.

Comment: @redneb yes I figured that out.It seems I am wrong.

Comment: @redneb updated it now using date and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a column that specifies the ordering within a day, then you can do:

```
SELECT sh.*
FROM (SELECT sh.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id, CAST(date_track as DATE)
                                ORDER BY date_track DESC
                               ) as seqnum
      FROM stocks_history sh
      WHERE product_id = 30 AND 
            date_track between '2016-09-02' and '2016-09-05'
     ) sh
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you have another column that has the ordering, then use that for the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I'm kinda new in this.So I will replace my query with this?or should I insert inside `FROM()`?because I tried this and gave me an error.

Comment: @rainalasa . . . This would replace your query.  You can, of course select only the columns that you want and make other changes.  The purpose of the answer is to explain the logic for getting the "latest" record per day.

Comment: going to update my question as I think there is no way getting the last transaction by just date only.Going to use datetime

Comment: this is the correct answer; you must have a column that includes time if you need to track ... time ...

Comment: @htxryan I have the column now it is `datetime` right?.How could I a column in his query?because I'm not quite familiar with his query.can you show me an example where to insert it?

Comment: @rainalasa . . . With a `datetime`, then you want the second `row_number()` expression.

Comment: @GordonLinoff could you show me where to insert my columns in you query?because I'm having a hard time figuring where to insert my column inside it.because the answer you gave me won't run.

Comment: `Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
The column prefix 'sh' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 10
No column name was specified for column 1 of 'sh'.`this was my error

Comment: @GordonLinoff kind of figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1
product_id
,product_name
,stock_on_hand
,stock_in
,stock_out
,date_track
FROM stocks_history
WHERE
product_id = 30
AND
date_track between '9/1/16' and '9/9/16'
order by date_track asc
```

Answer (score 0):

If date_track field of stocks_history table supports entry of date with time, then an ORDER BY can solve the issue. You can try the following query:

---

SELECT   product_id
         ,product_name
         ,stock_on_hand
         ,stock_in
         ,stock_out
         ,date_track
FROM     stocks_history
WHERE    product_id = 30 AND date_track between '9/1/16' and '9/9/16'
ORDER BY date_track DESC

---